# What is Qt's equivalent of SDL audio?

Tags: qt, ffmpeg, sdl

There is an old code that uses SDL audio to output music. I am porting it to Qt and I want to replace SDL audio with native Qt audio API.

The flow, in simplest terms, is this:

```
...
// Initialization
wanted_spec.callback = sdl_audio_callback;
SDL_OpenAudio(&wanted_spec, &spec);
...

// copies raw data to audio buffer
static void sdl_audio_callback(void *opaque, Uint8 *stream, int len)
```

Which audio Api of Qt should I be using? There is no video involved

Comment: http://www.sfml-dev.org/features.php

Comment: sfml looks interesting. Will dig into this.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132799/qt-phonon-open-raw-audio-data-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would use the higher level `Phonon` module, [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/phonon-module.html) are the API docs for it.  But because you are dealing with raw samples you will need the lower level `QtMultimedia` module, specifically the `QAudioOutput` class.  Docs [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtmultimedia.html).

Comment: I have decoded audio samples that need to be sent to output device / speakers. SDL does that. However, while Phonon provides an end-to-end solution to read media files from file on network, decode and playback them, it seems it does not work with already decoded samples. I need something more low level than Phonon.

Comment: @Saptarshi I've made an edit, I think this is how it's intended that you play decoded data.

Comment: `MediaObject` accepts `MediaSource` in `setCurrentSource()`, not `QBuffer`. Now `MediaSource` can be a filename, url, disc or QIODevice. So I tried initializing a `MediaSource` object from QIODevice but that does not play. I think the QIODevice option is just a mechanism of providing encoded data. So have you really used this code to play raw stream or it is an educated guess?

Comment: It was an educated guess, but after some more searching, I realise now that your right: Phonon is too high level.  Thankfully Qt has the much lower level `QtMultimedia` module where the `QAudioOutput` class can take a buffer of raw data and you can specify it's sample rate, etc. Before pushing it out the sound device.  I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: `QAudioOutput` seems to be the way to go. Will check it out

Answer (score 1):

**[SFML - Simple and Fast Multimedia Library](http://www.sfml-dev.org/features.php)**

> **Main features:**
>
> **Portable** SFML compiles on standard platforms like Windows (98, 2000, XP, Vista) and Unix systems (Linux, Mac OS X). As the library
> grows up, support for more operating systems will be added.
>
> **Object-oriented** SFML is written in C++ and provides an efficient, object-oriented design. It relies on standard patterns and idioms to
> provide a simple and robust framework.
>
> **Easy to use** SFML aims at being easy to manipulate. Effort is put on internal code to provide the simplest public interface.
>
> **Flexible** Instead of being one big API, SFML rather contains a lot of small packages, that can be chosen and combined according to the
> intended usage. You can use only the base package to get input and
> windowing, as well as the full graphics package with sprites and
> post-effects.
>
> **Easily integrable** SFML can be used in one or more windows, and/or can be integrated in existing interface components. Integration with
> existing graphical user interface (GUI) libraries is easy, so that you
> can add SFML views into complex interfaces built with Qt, wxWidgets,
> MFC or whatever.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Just checked a few examples and this approach will work.